# XSLT sort working with numbers but not text

Tags: xml, sorting, xslt

Given the following XML file:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<mappings>
<mapping>
  <class-a>C</class-a>
  <class-b>a</class-b>
</mapping>
<mapping>
  <class-a>B</class-a>
  <class-b>b</class-b>
</mapping>
<mapping>
  <class-a>A</class-a>
  <class-b>c</class-b>
</mapping>
</mappings>
```

And following XSLT file:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output method="xml" omit-xml-declaration="no" indent="yes" />
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
  <xsl:copy>
   <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
  </xsl:copy>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="mappings">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:apply-templates>
          <xsl:sort select="(name() = 'mapping')*class-a" data-type="text" order="ascending" />
    </xsl:apply-templates>
  </xsl:copy>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Produces this bad XML result:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<mappings>
   <mapping>
      <class-a>C</class-a>
      <class-b>a</class-b>
   </mapping>
   <mapping>
      <class-a>B</class-a>
      <class-b>b</class-b>
   </mapping>
   <mapping>
      <class-a>A</class-a>
      <class-b>c</class-b>
   </mapping>
</mappings>
```

Expected result is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<mappings>
   <mapping>
      <class-a>A</class-a>
      <class-b>c</class-b>
   </mapping>
   <mapping>
      <class-a>B</class-a>
      <class-b>b</class-b>
   </mapping>
   <mapping>
      <class-a>C</class-a>
      <class-b>a</class-b>
   </mapping>
</mappings>
```

Mappings should be sorted alphabetically based on `class-a` element values.

By using numbers in place of strings into `class-a` elements of input XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<mappings>
<mapping>
  <class-a>3</class-a>
  <class-b>a</class-b>
</mapping>
<mapping>
  <class-a>2</class-a>
  <class-b>b</class-b>
</mapping>
<mapping>
  <class-a>1</class-a>
  <class-b>c</class-b>
</mapping>
</mappings>
```

with either `data-type="text"` or `data-type="number"` in XSLT sort tag, we are getting the same expected result :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<mappings>
   <mapping>
      <class-a>1</class-a>
      <class-b>c</class-b>
   </mapping>
   <mapping>
      <class-a>2</class-a>
      <class-b>b</class-b>
   </mapping>
   <mapping>
      <class-a>3</class-a>
      <class-b>a</class-b>
   </mapping>
</mappings>
```

Does anybody know how to get expected result with text as well?

Comment: What does `(name() = 'mapping')*class-a` mean? `<xsl:sort>` expects XPath, this is not XPath.

Comment: I'm not sure that this is true XPath but found it from accepted answer:  [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2878809/xml-and-xslt-need-it-to-sort-only-certain-child-nodes)

Comment: Ohh, I see. That's a not applicable to your situation. You simply want to sort by `class-a`, just as @Rupesh suggests.

Comment: I eventually added my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally figured out how to get expected result:

`<xsl:sort select="class-a[name(..) = 'mapping']" data-type="text" />`

@Tomalak: thank you, you put me on the right track!

@Rupesh: your solution works well for simple cases (including the given example) but doesn't allow to sort solely `<mapping>` elements if there are also other kinds of elements inside the `<mappings>` tag having themselves `<class-a>` subelements...

Comment: `class-a[name(..) = 'mapping']` is the same as `class-a[../mapping]`. More general tip for your next question: Also add the edge cases to your sample.

Comment: @Tomalak Thank you for the shortcut. Ok I'll try to be more precise next time ;)

Answer (score 1):

you can try this:

```
        <xsl:sort select="class-a" data-type="text" order="ascending"  />
```